# Angular Scope length not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scope dumping into a table via an ng-repeat. This data is filtered by 3 different things, 2 selects and a text box. All of this works fine, but I need to echo out how many results are in the table. Using `{{ sounds.length }}` obviously doesn't work because this is a count prior to the filtering and filtering has no effect on that. so i added a variable `sound in soundsres = (sounds | filter: filters here)` but doing `{{ soundsres.length }}` echos out nothing with no errors in the console.

Below is a complete set of code. What am I missing here. all indications (i even checked the docs and several older threads here on SO) indicate that this should be working. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="gearsearch">
<select ng-model="stypesearch"><option>1</option></select>
<select ng-model="stypesearch2"><option>2</option></select>

<span>{{ soundsres.length }}</span>

<table ng-controller="GearController">
  <tr ng-repeat="sound in soundsres = (sounds | filter: gearsearch | filter: stypesearch | filter: stypesearch2)">
    <td>{{ sound.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ sound.model }}</td>
    <td>{{ sound.make }}</td>
    <td>{{ sound.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ sound.class }}</td>
    <td>{{ sound.status }}</td>
    <td>{{ sound.cost | currency }}</td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think that's a scoping issue. If you're placing your `GearController` to a div above `gearsearch` input and include the form and table in the same div it should work.

Comment: ah could be part of the issue. the problem is that `gearsearch` is a global search box that actually exists outside of the view itself. you can use `gearsearch` to filter any table in the entire application by leaving text in the box and switching views so i cant put `gearsearch` in the same div unfortunately

Comment: Oh OK, I see. I'll write an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `controllerAs` syntax and add the `soundRes` to your `MainController` or you could use `$parent.soundRes` to add your filter result to parent scope. I think the `controllerAs` method is more clear but both will work.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/vtk5tux2/).

(Sorry for my poor data model in the demo but I don't have a better one. But it's OK to show that the length is correctly updated.)

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('ViewController', function() {
  var vm = this,
        sameDate = new Date();
    
    sameDate.setMinutes(sameDate.getMinutes() - 5);
    var dateLimit = new Date(sameDate);
    
    var dates = [
        {
            name: 'test1',
         date: new Date(sameDate)
        },
        {
            name: 'test2',
         date: new Date(sameDate)
        },
        {
            name: 'test3',
         date: new Date()
        }];
        
    vm.dates = dates;
 })
 .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController() {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="mainCtrl.searchText"/>
    <select ng-model="mainCtrl.stypesearch"><option>1</option></select>
    <select ng-model="mainCtrl.stypesearch2"><option>2</option></select>

    <!--results: {{mainCtrl.filterRes.length}}-->
    results: {{filterRes.length}}
    <ul ng-controller="ViewController as viewCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="date in $parent.filterRes = ( viewCtrl.dates | filter:mainCtrl.searchText | filter: mainCtrl.stypesearch | filter: mainCtrl.stypesearch2 )">{{date}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: works great! really the only thing i was missing in this case was `$parent.` in my repeat query. changing ` sound in soundsres = (...)` to `sound in $parent.soundsres = (...)` did the trick! Thank you!